# USB adapter for sim card

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab

Is it possible to hook up a sim card through a USB adapter, to plug into the micro USB port of my galaxy tab e? I received it as a gift, and there is no sim card slot, WiFi only. If it exists, where would I be able to find one?

Comment: Depends upon whether the tablet supports it. Watch out for "UMTS sticks" (at least that's what they are called here), they are intended for exactly this purpose on tablets and laptops. You could simply take your tablet along you and check in your provider's nearest shop to verify before buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you google "usb adapter for sim card" you will find one
http://www.bestbuy.com/site/camera-memory-cards-usb-drives/readers-adapters/abcat0404007.c?id=abcat0404007
you can then use this USB to Micro-USB cable to plug your adapter into the micro usb port on your tablet [http://www.amazon.com/amp-USB-Micro-USB-Cable-Ft/dp/B002HMWQE2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HMWQE2)